# vcpkg is not able to find cmake.cmd when installing a package

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, msys2, vcpkg

I tried to install [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) on Windows 10. I followed the steps of the *Quick Start* section, but I get an error, when I try to run this command:

```
.\vcpkg install sdl2 curl
```

Error:

```
error checking existence of file "C:\msys64\usr\bin\cmake.cmd" The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I installed `msys64` and `cmake`:

```
pacman -S cmake
```

But there is still no `cmake.cmd` in `C:\msys64\usr\bin\`, only a `cmake.exe`.

I tried to manualy create `C:\msys64\usr\bin\cmake.cmd` with [this content](https://github.com/torch/luajit-rocks/blob/e9a2252889b9306638358a0db04fa7dd32de9bbd/luarocks/win32/bin/cmake.cmd):

```
if %1 == -E  (
cmake.exe  %* 
) else (
cmake.exe -G "NMake Makefiles"  -DWIN32=1 %*
)
pause 5
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it defaulted to an incorrect configuration. It just needed to be specified manually.

`msys` is configured automatically. So first reverse its installation:

- uninstall `cmake`
- uninstall `msys64`

Then perform a clean install for Windows:

- run `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`
- run `vcpkg update`
- run `vcpkg search sdl2`
- should find something, probably `sdl2:x86-windows` or `sdl2:x64-windows`, if it doesn't, it's a problem
- run `vcpkg install sdl2:x86-windows` or `vcpkg install sdl2:x64-windows`
- same for `curl`